# How to set permission on document using java code in alfersco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am able to set permission using alfresco dashboard but i want to do same with Java code but not get any idea...please if any one have example please upload and till now i am able to do following things.

I am able to create folder,store content,and change the version of content but not able to get any idea's how to set permission so please help me..

Comment: Using CMIS? Using a REST-ful service? Using a Java Behaviour? Other?

Comment: using java api ,please provide example

Comment: Did you try the [cunningly titled PermissionService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/security/PermissionService.html) yet? If not, why? If yes, where did you get stuck?

Comment: sorry ,till now i did"t know this cunningly titled permissionservice ,would u please provide some example how to use it...because i dont have any idea how to use it...please provide example

Answer (score 3):

Here is some example java code:

```
String userName = "myusername;"
PermissionService permissionservice = serviceRegistry.getPermissionService();
permissionService.setPermission(nodeRef, userName, PermissionService.CONSUMER, true);
NodeRef dir = fileFolderService.searchSimple(nodeRef, userName);
if (dir == null){
    dir = fileFolderService.create(nodeRef, userName, ContentModel.TYPE_FOLDER).getNodeRef();
    permissionService.setInheritParentPermissions(dir, false);//should not be visible to others
    permissionService.setPermission(dir, "GROUP_managers", PermissionService.COORDINATOR, true);
    permissionService.setPermission(dir, "GROUP_basicusers", PermissionService.CONSUMER, true);
}
permissionService.setPermission(dir, userName, PermissionService.CONTRIBUTOR, true);
```

Comment: thanks for providing example i am going to tried this one ,i hope this will work...for mee